# Where are the example applications of each of the DataStructures?

Tags: performance-tuning, reference-request

I recall a Wolfram website or Mma documentation that gives a non-trivial application of each DataStructure listed [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DataStructures.html), or at least each DataStructure Mma supported at the time. However, I haven't been able to find that web-page or documentation. Where is it?

Comment: Ideally the documentation page for each data structure would demonstrate how they work.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a work in progress. I've looked and haven't been able to find such a list of applications.  I've also looked at T Wickham-Jones recorded talks and couldn't find more examples.  There is a statement here https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2616747 that there will be a talk with examples sometime in the future.

Comment: Did you ever locate this?

Comment: Yes, goto the page for a one of the DataStructures (e.g. HashSet, DynamicArray). For many of the DataStructures they give a good example under Applications.